# Computing Jacobian And Passing to Scipy Minimize

Tags: python, math, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I know the jacobian is the first derivative, but I don't know how to compute it for my simple function (I tried online derivative calculators) and pass it to my scipy minimize function.

In code, here is the objective function (guess arrays can contain thousands of variables):

```
def objective(current_guesses_array, first_guesses_array):
        return np.sum(np.divide(np.square(current_guesses_array - first_guesses_array), first_guesses_array))
```

I think the Jacobian is like this, but definitely may have messed up here:

dx = 2x/y - 2

dy = 1 - (x^2/y^2)

In code:

```
def jacobian_for_minimize(self, x,a):
    dx = (2*x)/a - 2
    dy = 1 - (np.square(x) / np.square(a))
    return np.array([dx,dy])

minimize(objective,initial_guesses,args=initial_guesses,jac=jacobian_for_minimize,method='SLSQP')
```

After calling minimize, I get an error:
_slsqp.error: failed in converting 8th argument `g' of _slsqp.slsqp to C/Fortran array

According to another Stack overflow page, it means the objective function isn't returning a scalar, and it has to.

Can anyone tell where I went wrong with this?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer on how to compute a jacobian in python, or are you looking for one that specifically details what went wrong with *your* approach in computing the jacobian

Comment: I'm looking for what went wrong with my approach, but I am open to other approaches.

Comment: Your Jacobian is at least correct, if y (a) is your first_guess_array and x is the current_guess. I don't know about the minimize function.

Comment: Can you share the equations for the objective? I presume you have two variables only. Do we expect a function of the form `z = f(x, y)` ?

Comment: @newkid yes, we expect a function of that form where x and y are vectors.  The equation of the objective function is basically just SUM(((current_guesses_array - first_guesses_array)^2)/first_guesses_array)

Comment: For what it's worth: your derivatives are OK

Comment: Why not compute the Jacobian symbolically using, say, [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org)?